# Рекурсивная функция возвращает "мусор"

Tags: c++, рекурсия, дерево

Приветствую. Почему функция возвращает странное число, хотя должна возвращать 0 или 1? Функция поиска элемента в авл-дереве. Самое странное что если элемент найден, то функция собирается вернуть 1, но после выхода из этого уровня(уровня на котором был найден искомый элемент) рекурсии собирается возвращать огромное число       16249360.

```
int Search(AvlTree* current, string x)
{
  if (!current)
      return 0;
  if (current->info._numberOfFlight == x)
  {
      current->info.set();
      return 1;
  }
  else
  {
      if (x < current->info._numberOfFlight)
          Search(current->left, x);
      else
          Search(current->right, x);
  }
}
```

Comment: Поставьте уровень предупреждений 4 (самый высокий). Поначалу будет надоедать (ругается на каждую мелочь), но зато потом привыкнете и код станете заметно чище.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В блоке ELSE напишите не `Search(...)` а `return Search(...)`. Дело в том, что ваша функция возвращает "адекватное" значение только в том случае, когда "провалится" в один из if-ов.